# PHP using one array as keys for subarray of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So i got one single dimensional array like:

```
Array
(
[0] => md5
[1] => name
[2] => description
[3] => url
)
```

and one multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => md5#1
            [1] => name1
            [2] => desc1
            [3] => url1
         )  
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => md5#2
            [1] => name2
            [2] => desc2
            [3] => url2
         )  
)
```

and I want to use values of first array as keys for subarrays of the multidimensional one, so the output should look like:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [md5] => md5#1
                [name] => name1
                [desription] => desc1
                [url] => url1
             )  
        [1] => Array
            (
                [md5] => md5#2
                [name] => name2
                [description] => desc2
                [url] => url2
             )  
    )
```

Alternatively(as a bit offtopic question), how can I sort the elements of multidimensional array by values of md5 if they keys of subarray are not [md5] but [0]?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're sure in order of elements in both arrays - `array_combine`. Sorting is done with `usort`.

Comment: But how do I do that exactly? If I try to `array_combine($keysarray, $multiDarray)` I get `array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements` because i think it's trying to set the keys for the [0] => Array, and not for it;s elements.

Comment: That's why there is the foreach loop see his answer. It goes through each item on the first level and applies the combine on its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For combining values of two arrays where values of one are keys, and values of other are values, use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) function:

```
$keysArray  = [];
$multiArray = [];
$result_array = [];
foreach ($multiArray as $value) {
    $result_array[] = array_combine($keysArray, $value);
}
```

For sorting - use `usort` and define your custom function:

```
usort($result_array, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['md5'], $b['md5']); });
```

Comment: damn, I had 1 extra element in 1st array that i was not aware of and that where this error came from ^^ 
thanks a lot!

Comment: btw how do I save the value of `$result_array` outside the foreach? probably should put `&` but where? otherwise `$result_array` got only 1 element if printed outside the foreach

Comment: of course I did, thanks again! i guess it would work the same with `array_push()` instead of `[]` right? sry for dumb questions but i'm trying to understand how arrays exactly work

Comment: Yes, `array_push($array, $value)` is the same as `$array[] = $value`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the functional-style equivalent of @u_mulder's answer.

This technique merely applies the array of key names as the keys for every row in the array.

Using arrow function syntax (available since PHP7.4), allows the custom callback to access the globally scoped `$keys` array without needing to explicitly write `use($keys)` in the function declaration.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DLgH9))

```
$first = ['md5#1', 'name1', 'description1', 'url1'];
$second = ['md5#2', 'name2', 'description2', 'url2'];
$multidimArray = [$first, $second];

$keys = ['md5', 'name', 'description', 'url'];

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => array_combine($keys, $row),
        $multidimArray
    )
);
```