# php - Combine multiple array into single multi-dimension array and assign key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the simpliest way to do merge multiple array values into a single multi-dimension array. For example, I have several arrays (**$arr_a**, **$arr_b**) like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => a1
    [1] => a2
    [2] => a3
)

Array
(
    [0] => b1
    [1] => b2
    [2] => b3
)
```

The keys array (**$keys**) for new array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => key1
    [1] => key2
    [2] => key3
)
```

I want combine these array to a single array with keys like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => a1
            [key2] => a2
            [key3] => a3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => b1
            [key2] => b2
            [key3] => b3
        )

)
```

I tried this this code

```
$ouput = array_map(null, $arr_a, $arr_b);
```

But I can't add array keys by this code..

Comment: `array_combine($keys_array, $values_array)`

Comment: Why post resolving advice as a comment?  Were you going to close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72546975/2943403 from 2 days ago.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think you didn't carefully read my problem and the problem you identified as similar. this is not fair

Comment: Look at [how incredibly accurate the duplicate page is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72596825/2943403) at resolving your specific problem.   I am confident that if you would have found that page before asking your question, you would have either solved your own problem without asking, or you would have posted a better failed coding attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine each array with the keys, you can use something like `array_combine()` which can take your keys array and add them to the value array.

To apply this and combine the array, using `array_map()` with `array_combine` as the callback makes it possible with combining the two arrays as well.  Using arrow functions also means you don't have to worry about the scope of the keys array..

```
$arr_a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
$arr_b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];

$keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];

print_r(array_map(fn ($arr) => array_combine($keys, $arr), [$arr_a, $arr_b]));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => a1
            [key2] => a2
            [key3] => a3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => b1
            [key2] => b2
            [key3] => b3
```

Comment: So the PHP code will be `$output = array_map(function($arr) use ($keys) {return array_combine($keys, $arr);}, [$arr_a, $arr_b]);`

Comment: @MdJahidKhanLimon, yes - that is the equivalent code when not using arrow functions.